# Regex to capture and reposition the same pattern

Tags: regex

I have a list of numbers that I would like to reformat, but I'm having difficulty with (I think) the substitution -- I'm capturing the groups as I intend to, but they aren't being rendered the way I expect them to be.

Here's some of the text:

```
Rear seal: 
102
111
112
113
137
156
```

And the expected output is this:

```
Rear seal:
102   111   112
113   137   156
```

I'm using this regex to distinguish the first, second, and third lines:
`(\d{3}[\n\r])(\d{3}[\n\r])(\d{3}[\n\r])` coupled with `\1\t\2\t\3\n` for the substitution. But for some reason it comes out as

```
Rear seal: 
102
    111
    112

113
    137
    156
```

I'm using the excellent site regex101.com for testing, but I could use some human input. Specific link is
https://regex101.com/r/R7niEU/1 for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The newline should not be part of the capture group or else it will also be in the replacement. https://regex101.com/r/WQoBc6/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I finally got there too, but post this as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are capturing the newline in the capturing group. That way it will also be part of the replacement.

You can only capture the digits and match the newline instead.

Then replace with `\1\t\2\t\3\n`

```
(\d{3})[\n\r](\d{3})[\n\r](\d{3})[\n\r]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQoBc6/1)